# Discrete Valuation Ring properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, proof-writing

From Dummit and Foote problem about the Discrete Valuation Ring $R$ with field $K$

> Prove that for each nonzero element $x \in K$ that either $x$ or $x^{-1}$ is in $R$

My attempt:

$v(1) = v(x\cdot x^{-1}) = v(x) + v(x^{-1}).$ I show $v(1) = 0$ via $v(1) = v(1\cdot 1) = v(1) + v(1) \implies v(1) = 0$. So we have $v(x) = -v(x^{-1})$ Then we can conclude if either $v(x) > 0$ or $v(x^{-1}) > 0$ then the other can't be in $R$.

But my problem comes if $v(x) = 0$, then both $x, x^{-1} \in R$. What's wrong with this?

Comment: Is that a problem?

Comment: Well, I guess that's my problem. It easily helps show the next part that a unit is in $R$ iff $v(x) =0$. But I guess I just have a problem semantically about the "or."

Comment: Both $1$ and $1^{-1} \in R$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

English is an awkward language for expressing logical connectives. Despite the use of "either ... or ...", the problem did not intend for $x \in R$ and $x^{-1} \in R$ to be exclusive; it merely wants you to show *at least* one of the two statements is true.

Comment: Thank you. As I commented earlier, my problem was with the wording.